# How to escape single quote in sql which is causing' quoted string not properly terminated '?

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to read terms from a database (>10K) and I'm using that term in another query. I'm getting the following error in Oracle:

> quoted string not properly terminated'

I did

```
term.replaceAll("'", "\\'");
```

but that doesn't seem to do the job from me. Besides, these terms are tokens from documents when they are converted to text. Is there a regular expression that can overcome this problem?

The exact SQL query is:

```
String sql = "Select * from indexDB where (DocID=" + d.getDocId() + "and Term='" + term + "')";
```

I'm using Java. The replacement doesn't work for me.

Comment: You need to read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: See also http://bobby-tables.com/ for details on how to use parameterized queries in whatever language you're using.  This will protect you from SQL injection that Oded referred to.

Comment: Yeah went through it and parameterized query did it !! Thanks so much !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can escape a single quote by repeating it:

```
term.replaceAll("'","''");
```

An even better option would be a parameterized query.  For an example, we'd have to know your client language.

Comment: More special characters in ***Oracle***, no only the _character_ **'** ?